# Permission in django.

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

In hierarchical level of organisation how to provide permission at department level as data about each employee will be in same table.

here S(Employee) is basic unit in whole organization.[image: hierarchy of Employees]

Now I want D department can see access,chagne only employees who are under them,
similarly for upper level,
Can anyone tell me how should I start ?

Comment: This isn't a particularly good question, as there's no MVCE here, and you're really asking a number of questions -database design and user permissions at the very least - I'd have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see if you can edit this appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be django?

This traversal style layout looks more like a job for pyramid.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mptt
seems a good starting point for your tree structure, but with the permission system you are on your own

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your managers' user object have a foreign key named unit to the level they represent (B1, C3, ...)

First you need a way to get all the employee who are descendants. Like cleder mentioned, django-mptt will make your life way easier for that. Simply run `user.unit.get_leafnodes()` with mptt correctly setup and you have all your managed employee.
See [MPTTModel.get_leaf_nodes](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/mptt.models.html#mptt.models.MPTTModel.get_leafnodes).

Then you need to use that information.

If you are using the django admin, you can use that in [ModelAdmin.get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset). get_queryset take the request as an argument. Simply access `request.user` and you're back on your feet. You can then lock things down a bit more with [ModelAdmin.has_change_permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) and the family.

If you want more control, have a look at the generic class based views. Your `views.py` can be as simple as that:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeList(generic.ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.unit.get_leafnodes() 

class EmployeeCreate(generic.edit.CreateView):
    fields = ["name"]
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.unit.get_leafnodes()

class EmployeeUpdate(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    fields = ["name"]
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.unit.get_leafnodes()
```

The edit views will create a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) based on the object returned by the queryset. The fields attribute is required.
See the doc on [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects) and [those based on models forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).

Comment: Ok I will read those docs. Thanks for Info. Hopefully this also solve problem of permisssion